# Unity PlayerPrefs not saving across re-installs on Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, apk

I have a 'Money' PlayerPref, I'll give myself money, make it save, upon reinstalling the android APK, it deletes ALL the playerpref's, including owned objects ETC. please help.

Comment: The data gets removed when an item gets uninstalled. During an update however, the data persists. To keep data across devices or re-install, you need to save the data on a remote server.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn thank you haha, I take it Google Play will support the updates needed to not delete the data? Also how do I close this question as answered lol, new here

Comment: You cannot close as answered until someone answers the question (not a comment). You can delete the question but that is highly not recommended. I would recommend that you just leave it open until an answer is given, and you can accept it if you like it. This will give you and the other person reputation points. Welcome to SO!

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn if you want to just put an answer in then id accept it haha, it was all the info I needed ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any data that is saved on an android device is associated to the application. When the application gets uninstalled, so does its data.

When an application is updated however, the data precists on the device and only the application gets updated.

To allow data to persist across devices or installs you need to use a remote server to store the data, such as Google's [Saved Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) Service.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to necessarily save your data in any of the clouds. ***

> Save the data on the external sd card in custom folder

*** and access that data from the game everytime. Make sure to include the if(!data.null) exception handeling for security purpose.